# what's the difference between two code scenario

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Scenario1:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =
              [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.stateZips = dictionary;
[dictionary release];
```

Scenario2:

```
self.stateZips = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Answer (score 4):

dependes on `stateZips` property.
If it is `retained`:
Scenario 1: `stateZips` is properly retained ( a release on `stateZips` will call its dealloc). also local dictionary is released then and there.
Scenario 2: `stateZips` is retained twice ( a release in `stateZips` will not call its dealloc as it is still retained).

If it is `assigned`:
Scenario 1: `stateZips` points to released dictionary and accessing it else where might result in crash.
Scenario 2: `stateZips` is properly retained ( a release on `stateZips` will call its dealloc).

`copy` is not being considered, as i believe its not your intention (at least in this piece of code)

Comment: Sorry Tatvamasi, I didn't see your question when I posted mine. they are very similar; I'm up voting yours but I'll leave mine too, since it looks like there are some differences.

Answer (score 1):

Both cause `self.stateZips` to be set to a dictionary initialized with the file pointed to in `plistPath`.

But in the second, the pointer to the initialized dictionary was not saved, and as it's an object with a retain count of +1 technically a `release` message needs to be sent to it in some place, to balance the memory management. But as there is no way to retrieve the pointer to that object, you'll end up with a memory leak.

Two exceptions apply:

**1.Garbage Collection**
If you're in a garbage collected environment, both are the same. Well, they are not the same, but the result is similar.

**2.Property type**
If the setter for `stateZips` simply assigns the pointer, then you can release the object using the ivar pointer. Then these two pieces of code have only one difference: in the former, the object is released right after it's used. In the latter, it's just "undefined". Without the context, it's hard to determine if this object was released or not, and when.

Comment: Is this really correct?  Surely the compiler can optimize this so that only a single retain is called?  In all the stuff I've read about memory management in objective-c - I've never seen an example of scenario2 as being a leak.

Comment: Scenario2 *is* a leak if the property retains.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that stateZips is a property with the retain attribute.

In Scenario 1. A dictionary is created with a retain count of 1 in the first line.  In the second line the property will call retain again, increasing the retain count to 2.  Finally the retain count is decremented by the release.  This will leave the dictionary with the correct retain count.

In Scenario 2, the retain is only called once.

The net effect of the two scenarios is the same.  The dictionary object will be retained, and you will need to include a release in the dealloc method of the class.

If this were not correctly handled by the compiler, it would be very hard indeed following the retain/release rules of objective-c.